# SSRS Value By Date

Tags: sorting, date, reporting-services

Ok, I've seen similar questions on here, but nothing exactly the same.  I am creating reports based on a cube that reads data from a DW.  A lot of the reports tend to be along the lines of Value by Something By Week or Value By Something By Month.  Everything seems ok, but the week and month (columns) don't order correctly.  Week 10 goes before Week 9, February comes before January, etc.  Im very frustrated bc I can't get these things to work correctly.

To add to this, at some point my customer needs to be able to write their own reports against the cube using Reportbuilder 3.0.  So, I am reluctant to rely on manually editing the query.  SURELY there is some obvious way to do this.  In my DimDate I have a weekname that is a varchar, a week that is date, etc.  Same for month.

Im missing something obvious here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The sort order would make sense (varchars are strings {"Week 10", "Week 9"}, and {"February", "January"}) in that they are coming before their respective pair in the examples you've given, assuming an ASCII type of sort on the string values.

There are multiple ways to have ascending sort with strings as column headers (assuming ASCII type sorting on the string field):

- Ensure week numbers are two digits in length e.g. "Week 9" would become "Week 09". This will ensure that the week columns are sorted in ascending order (or descending order, which ever is the case).
- Add a month number in front of the month name e.g. "01 January", "02 February" -> You will still need two digit month numbers otherwise you will get the same issue you had with week numbers.
- Use formatted dates as opposed to strings, as dates will be sorted properly.

Alternatively, if the issue is being caused in the dimension within the cube you can ensure any **order by** clauses are on keys, and not name fields.

Comment: Good idea on the first two.  Hadn't thought of that.  However, I tried using formatted dates and I ended up with nothing being displayed at all.  It was very odd.  I couldn't figure out what was wrong.

For the record, the dates show up ordered correctly in the cube.